# Is there a word to say that a vector takes the size such that the matrix notation makes sense?

Tags: matrices, notation, word-problem

I am handling with a vector, lets call it $\iota$ which should describe a vector of ones. While writing a text I realized that it is somewhat cumbersome to include a subscript describing its length, e.g. $\iota_N$ in all the formulas. Is there a specific word/ property I can assign to the vector $\iota$ which states that the vector is from the 'appropriate' dimension, such that basic algebra makes sense (If multiplied with a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R} ^{N \times N}$, it should be clear that $X\iota$ is such that $\iota\in\mathbb{R}^N$)?

Comment: I would certainly avoid cumbersome subscripts.  People understand that sizes need to match up in linear algebra.  So, it is sufficient to say that the matrices are of "appropriate size so that multiplication makes sense."  You can also initially say that $v \in \mathbb{R}^N$ if that is the correct size.  I don't know what that symbol is you use, I don't know how to make it in latex.

Comment: For example, people understand that the identity matrix $I$ has size appropriate to the problem, so it is not necessary to write $I_N$.  Most linear algebra books talk about eigenvalues in terms of the equation $(A-\lambda I)x=0$, and so on, rather than $(A-\lambda I_N)x_N = 0$.  The notation $v_N$ or $x_N$ can also be misunderstood as the $N$th coordinate of a vector.

Comment: The only issue is if the identity $I$ or the all-1 vector $v$ occurs twice in the same analysis (or equation) with different sizes both times, in which case you can clarify with subscripts or superscripts.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Well in my case I am searching for a nice describtion that I can give before using this vector all the time over and over again because I need it several times (with different 'sizes'). For the sake of clarity it would be better to give sub/ superscripts, but in some cases the size is just ugly and wastes space by not buying anything (lets say $\iota_{T-N-1}$)

Comment: What about just redundantly using the phrase "where $\iota$ is the all-1 column vector of appropriate size'' whenever needed? A little redundancy does not hurt, especially as texts are generally read piecemeal, rather than cover-to-cover.  Nobody will remember a definition given several sections (or chapters) before anyway, even if they do read cover-to-cover, especially if that definition is non-standard.

Comment: Another symbol could be $\vec{1}$, I have used that notation before.